# Como escolher algoritmo de coloração entre Welsh/Powell e DSATUR?

Tags: grafo

Quando que eu devo usar Welsh/Powell e quando devo usar DSATUR?
Para que tipo de grafo cada algoritmo funciona melhor?

Comment: DSATUR é um algoritmo guloso de coloração, confere?

Comment: Não conheço esses algoritmos, então preciso bater se as fontes que estou buscando batem (ainda mais porque só estou conseguindo fontes em francês, que eu não domino)